# Compute sum of variations - ammount of password variants

Tags: combinatorics

I think it is rather my lack of correct vocabulary, that I failed to find answer to this question.
I have a variation, eg. passwords, that can have any (and repeated) or none of character in the list. So, for 4 letter password consisting of alpha lowercase, I'll have $26^4$ passwords (at least, I think so. If otherwise, please let me know).
So now, how do I get variants of all passwords from 1 to 4 letters, if I want avoid doing $26^1+26^2+26^3+26^4$?
And, use of sum is NOT what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of words of length between $n$ and $m$ inclusive over an alphabet of $k$ letters is 
$$\frac{k^{m+1}-k^n}{k-1} $$
In your case
$$ \frac{26^5-26^1}{25}=475254.$$

Comment: I like your m-n range, I think this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the geometric series
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^i = a^1 + \cdots + a^n = \frac{a^{n+1}-a}{a-1}
$$
In your case with $a=26$ you get for general $n$ the expression $26 (26^n-1)/25$.

Comment: Thank you for idea with geomethric series - I wouldn't figure that relation out I think...

Comment: You're welcome.